# Not getting correct value of each line in CSV file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

CSV:

```
name,age
Jack,38
Tom,43
```

Code:

```
CSV.foreach(filename, :headers => true) do |row|
 name, age = row
 puts name # expected Jack, but getting ["name", "Jack"]
end
```

I want to get each name and age but it doesn't work properly.

Comment: can you specify which version of Ruby you're using? and the exact console output you're getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting `:headers => true` in [`new`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.1/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-new) causes `foreach` to yield a [`CSV::Row`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.1/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV/Row.html) object for each row instead of a plain Ruby array. See the [`new`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.1/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-new) documentation for more information.

To access the actual row fields, you need to use `row.fields`:

```
CSV.foreach(filename, :headers => true) do |row|
 name, age = row.fields
 puts name
end
```

I'm not aware of a way to skip headers, use `CSV.foreach`, and still get a plain array for each row.

Comment: You can also use `row.to_a`. I expect `to_a` is an alias of `fields`, or vice-versa.

Answer (score 2):

`name, age = row.fields` has the disadvantage that it requires the headers to be in a particular order (`'name'` followed by `'age'`). Normally when using CSV files you should not care about the order of the headers.

Let's create the file:

```
s=<<~_
name,age
Jack,38
Tom,43
_
```

```
filename = 't.csv'
File.write(filename,s)
  #=> 24
```

You could write the following:

```
require 'csv'

CSV.foreach(filename, :headers => true) do |row|
  age, name = row.values_at('age', 'name')
  puts name
  puts age
end
```

displays

```
Jack
38
Tom
43
```

Obviously, I could have instead written:

```
name, age = row.values_at('name', 'age')
```

See [CSV::Row#values_at](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV/Row.html#method-i-values_at). Alternatively (better), you could simply write:

```
CSV.foreach(filename, :headers => true) do |row|
  puts row['name']
  puts row['age']
end
```

See [CSV::Row#[]](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV/Row.html#method-i-5B-5D).

Comment: @yu-coder, If the headers are `'a'`, `'b'`, `'c'`, `'d'` and `'e'` and you want the values of `'e'` and `'b'`, you could write `b, e = row.values_at('b', 'e')` or `_,b,_,_,e = rows.fields`. That part is similar but the former works regardless of the order of the headers. Also, if we are given an array `arr` of the headers of interest, in a particular order (e.g., `arr = ['e', 'c']`), we can write `puts row.values_at(*arr)` or `arr.each { |header| puts row[header] }`, whereas that is problematic when using `fields`.

Comment: Understood. Thank you!